# I can't figure out why setState function not working for setting a value

Tags: reactjs, jsx

Hope you are all well and healthy.
I am learning react and following a tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DLX62G4lc44&t=9947s
Time is also mentioned in YouTube video where I got stuck. This is my Code:

This is the ToDoComponent

```
import React from 'react';

function ToDoItem(props){
    return(
        <div className="tasks">
            <label>{props.item.taskName}</label><input type="checkbox" 
            checked={props.item.completed} onChange={() => props.handleChange(props.item.Id)}/> 
        </div>  
    );
}


export default ToDoItem;
```

And This is the App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import ToDoItem from './components/ToDoItem';
import toDoData from './datas/tododata';


class App extends Component{
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {todos : toDoData}
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(Id){
    this.setState(prevState => {
      
      const updatedToDos = prevState.todos.map(todo => {
        if(todo.Id == Id){
          console.log(todo.completed)
          todo.completed = !todo.completed 
          console.log(todo.completed)
        }
        return todo
      })
      
      return{
        todos : updatedToDos
      }
        
    })


  }

  render(){
    var toDoComponent = this.state.todos.map(
      item => 
        <ToDoItem key={item.Id} item={item} handleChange={this.handleChange}/>
      );

    return(
      <div>
        {toDoComponent}
      </div>
    );
  }
}


export default App;
```

Now look at this picture. When I click the CheckBox, the setState is called twice and the CheckBox value is not changing because of that.
[image]
I can't find where the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are using React's [strict mode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html), which causes `setState` updater functions, and other lifecycle functions, to be called twice in order to test whether these functions are actually pure, as they should be.

It seems the problem here is that you are mutating your state, on this line:

```
todo.completed = !todo.completed
```

Here, you are modifying an object that is part of the previous state. So you are *modifying* the previous state when you should only be creating a new state and leaving the previous one alone.

Strict mode is intended to identify these kinds of problems.

To solve this, make sure that your `setState` updater does not mutate the state:

```
const updatedToDos = prevState.todos.map(todo => {
    if(todo.Id == Id){
        console.log(todo.completed)
        const newTodo  = { ...todo, completed: !todo.completed }
        console.log(newTodo.completed)
        return newTodo;
    }

    return todo
})
```

Comment: Dude thank you so much for your fast replay. This SOLVED the problem !!!! ^_^
But the same coding is done in Tutorial too. Why is it working there then. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DLX62G4lc44 at 2:46:28. You can see I just copied him. Working for him, not me. Would you kind enough to explain.
Is he did something that I missed.

Comment: @Md.IrfanOmee Looks like that's definitely a mistake on the instructor's part. Either he did that by accident or didn't know any better, but he definitely shouldn't be doing that. I suspect he probably wasn't using strict mode so he didn't encounter an issue.

Comment: Thank you from bottom of my heart. Have a BEAUTIFUL DAY !!!!!!